# In Ubuntu 13.04 I cannot get Firefox to open .torrent files by default

Tags: default, bittorrent

I am trying to get firefox to open torrent files by default, it only gives me the option to cancel or save.... If I look in the Application section of preferences assigning Bittorrent or Torrent files is not an option they do not appear as assigned or unassigned.
I am trying to open it with deluge by default but can't get it to open with anything so not sure that is relevant.

Obviously am able to save and then open with deluge after but a crap option if trying to download a bunch of stuff at once.

Comment: Check this question http://askubuntu.com/q/122930/169736