# How to set Firefox to use Transmission?

Tags: firefox

I am trying to download torrents and when I select a torrent it asks for a application and there isn't one in the default and upon searching /bin I find none.

I do some searching and see that I can tell Firefox what app to use for magnet links, magnet doesn’t even show up in the list of things I can associate a default application with.

Comment: you could possibly find your answer in the link: [How can I get Firefox to open torrent files with Transmission?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/384375/how-can-i-get-firefox-to-open-torrent-files-with-transmission/)

Comment: good to know that it helped.. and welcome to AU ..if you like, please visit [Getting started with AU](http://askubuntu.com/help)

Answer (score 0):

Look for Transmission in /usr/share/applications.

Specifically look for **transmission-gtk**