# Ubuntu and Torrents

Tags: bittorrent, default-programs

I cannot download magnetic links from any site. I have downloaded multiple torrent clients such as [Vuze, bittorent client](http://www.vuze.com), and [Transmisson](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) which was already downloaded when I got the computer.

When I click the magnetic link it brings up a small tab asking me to open it with other software, the problem is my software which I downloaded is not there and it only shows my documents that I saved such as word documents or my music collection.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the mime type (how an application determines which file to open with which application) is not registered.

One option is to copy the magnet link, open your torrent client and use option "open magnet URI" and paste the magnet URI there.

Second option, download .torrent file or create a plain text document with extension .torrent and paste the magnet link in it. Open the downloaded or created torrent file in your torrent client.

Third and most convenient solution, set up your browser so that it can open magnet link.
Here is guide for firefox browser - [How can I get Firefox to open torrent files with Transmission?](https://askubuntu.com/q/384375/35775). You have to adjust the steps if configuring for any other client like vuze.

**Most important thing to remember, most application get installed in `/usr/bin`, so you need to search the torrent client there.**

Answer (score 0):

i think , you should use  **uget**  it can handle magnet link as well as .torrent files ,it is small and very affective application for Ubuntu.