# Transmission Remote (software center) does not initiate downloads in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bittorrent, transmission

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04. I installed the "Transmission Remote" via software center.

But for some reason when I click magnets, transmission does not initiate any downloads, instead it opens a "Launch application" window and I don't know where transmission is located to choose it as the default application to open magnets.

In Ubuntu 12.04 transmission was installed by default and always worked fine.

What should I do?

Comment: Torrent files are not meant for "opening". Transmission remote  probably expects a link to a .torrent file or a magnet link. You need to copy the link, and paste it in Transmission remote.

Comment: @mikewhatever: Thanks, I updated the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Firefox open magnet-links in Transmission?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/122930/how-can-i-make-firefox-open-magnet-links-in-transmission)

Comment: Hi Mike thanks but no it's not a duplicate because the above link does not provide a path to "Transmission" when the "Launch application" appears. Edited the question again ;)

Comment: You are right, `/usr/bin/transmission-gtk` is not a link, it's called path to an executable, but it is provided in one of the answers.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike! Here is my error: I was searching inside "/bin", not "/usr/bin/". Also:  Updating the system automatically puts Transmission in the "Launch application" window ;)

Answer (score 1):

An automatic update of Ubuntu 14.04 inserted transmission inside the "Launch application" window.

One can also set the application by navigating through the file system to this address: `/usr/bin/transmission-gtk`.

[image: picture]