# how to save magnet links as files?

Tags: software-installation, firefox, internet, file-sharing, transmission

How do I configure firefox not to use [transmission](https://askubuntu.com/q/122930/45156) but to save magnet links as files?
[image: transmission]

see also:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol

Notably, `.torrent` files are downloadable:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ll Downloads/*.torrent
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir 30136 Nov 12 14:24 Downloads/ubuntu-17.10-server-amd64.iso.torrent
thufir@dur:~$
```

Comment: What do you mean as a file? you want to save the link into a file? or you want the related torrent file to be saved ?

Comment: save the link in a file.  thx.

Comment: A magnet link is basically a link. Just copy it and paste it into  to a file. However, do not confuse it with a `.torrent` file. Pasting a link into .torrent file does not make it one.