# Magnet links don't work in Google Chrome

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

Just some days ago magnet links stopped working in Google Chrome, but it works fine in Firefox. Tested to disable all extensions, but it still don't work. Any suggestions?

Running Ubuntu 12.04.2.

Answer (score 1):

When I first run Google Chrome in Ubuntu 13.04 , and I clicked a magnetic link, Chrome asked me how I would like to handle it. Because I had already installed the program 'Transmission BitTorrent Client', Chrome proposed to use this program.

Maybe Google Chrome is not your default browser?

Here is [an answer from Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108925/how-to-tell-chrome-what-to-do-with-a-magnet-link)

Comment: Chrome is my default browser. Worked like a charm just some days ago. Tested the method you linked, and it dosn't work, tested to set both Transmission and Deluge as applications.

Comment: I find that resetting the Chrome profile by deleting the folder works.  Go to Home, press CTRL & H to show hidden files & click on .config then find the folder google-chrome and delete that.  As said before, all that does it reset your Google Chrome as if you'd just installed it.  Make sure that you have sync'd all your bookmarks before you do it & you will need to install your extensions again.