# Torrent magnet links open new window but not transmission

Tags: google-chrome, transmission, torrent-client

I've installed Ubuntu and Lubuntu a few times now and some of those times I've had the following problem, which I currently have. When I click a torrent magnet link in Chrome (usually from Pirate bay), instead of opening transmission, the only thing that happens is a new Chrome window opens.

Upon other installations, I've not had this problem; transmission opened just as I'd like.

I've tried using Chrome's extension .torrent to Transmission, but I get the error

> unable to contact http ://localhost:9091/transmission/rpc
>
> no response

Comment: This should help

[How to tell chrome what to do with a magnet link][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/108925/how-to-tell-chrome-what-to-do-with-a-magnet-link

Comment: Note: I'm using Lubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Note: Firefox correctly handles magnet links.

Comment: @BiggJJ I tried following Chan-Ho Suh's solution there, but to no avail.

Comment: What version of Google chrome are you running? I use Google Chrome 28.0.1500.71 and it correctly handles magnet links withot to do nothing.

Comment: You are trying to open a `magnet://` link, or downloading a proper `.torrent` file?

Comment: @Braiam A magnet.

Comment: just press right click in magnet link and copy it after that go to transsmion program and but it on it

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Version 28.0.1500.71

Comment: @Mahmoud20070 That works, thanks. But it's still sub-optimal since I'd prefer to just be able to click in Chrome and have Transmission opened automatically with the torrent.

Comment: Can you post `cat /usr/share/app-install/desktop/chrome.desktop | grep MimeType` and `cat /usr/share/application/chrome.desktop | grep MimeType`?

Comment: `cat: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/chrome.desktop: No such file or directory` and `cat: /usr/share/application/chrome.desktop: No such file or directory`

Comment: Ok, lets try to start clean, uninstall all transmission packages `apt-get purge transmission*` and install just `transmission-gtk`. I've tested again and I just don't see where things went wire.

Comment: @Braiam I re-installed transmission (per your suggestion) but am still having the same problem.

Comment: This happened to me (on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS) when Chromium was set as my default browser. If Firefox was set as my default browser, then Chromium instead started up a new empty tab in Firefox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use torrent to transmission, you have to allow remote access in transmission  under preferences/remote.

If you want to open magnet links in transmission by clicking on them, you need to patch the /usr/bin/xdg-open script, [here's](https://gist.github.com/tomb0y/7813895#file-xdg-open) mine for reference. 
The added lines are 311 and 490-493.

Comment: That was not exactly the solution I was looking for (I don't like having to patch my OS stuff, even if it's just a silly wrapper script). *But it worked perfectly.* (I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with Chromium set as my default browser.)

Comment: can i copy and repaste the whole thing again on lubuntu 14.04 lts.

Comment: @john : I'm on 14.04 too, using the same script, it should work :) (but please make a backup just in case)

Comment: the gist link is a 404

Comment: @m0sa : should be fixed now

Answer (score 13):

You can change the default handler for magnet links by editing the file *.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list*. Add the association to the two sections in the file like this (leaving other entries in those sections intact):

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/magnet=transmission-gtk.desktop

[Added Associations]
x-scheme-handler/magnet=transmission-gtk.desktop
```

Log out and log back in for the change to take effect.

Comment: I tried this but I hasn't seemed to work. Still chrome just opens a new browser (or a new tab separate from the others; however you wanna put it).

Comment: There's no `transmission.desktop` in `transmission`'s source file. Check if you meant `transmission-gtk.desktop`.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, I tried with and without the `-gtk`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed `transmission-gtk` then the solution is easy.

```
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/command '/usr/bin/transmission-gtk %s' --type String
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/enabled --type Boolean true
```

The first one adds `transmission-gtk` as handler for `magnet://` links the second enable it.

Since chrome/ium uses `xdg-open` this is the best method for setting the handlers. You can replace `/usr/bin/transmission-gtk` for any client you like. This works for almost all flavors of Ubuntu.

You can test this issuing in the terminal `xdg-open "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:f41989f9797a88505f9e258d5e5d1354c3731a99"` (downloads Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit)

---

Other solution is using `xdg-mime`:

```
xdg-mime default transmission-gtk.desktop application/x-bittorrent
xdg-mime default transmission-gtk.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet
```

In case you don't have the mime-types installed use `xdg-mime install x-scheme-handler/magnet`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked. Still, even when I try your test from the terminal (to download Ubuntu), it opens a new Chrome window.

Comment: @QuinnCulver What's the output of `gconftool-2 -g /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/command`?

Comment: The output is: `/usr/bin/transmission-gtk %s`

Comment: @QuinnCulver and `gconftool-2 -g /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/enabled`? Try logging out to force the values to be updated.

Comment: The output is: `true`. I'd rebooted last time I tried your suggested commands. I'll try again; this time I'll only log out.

Comment: @QuinnCulver I updated my responce with yet another solution.

Answer (score 0):

> unable to contact http ://localhost:9091/transmission/rpc
>
> no response

To fix this

1. Install `transmission-remote`
   `sudo apt-get install transmission-remote`
2. Start transmission (`transmission-gtk`) before adding .torrent files
3. *Enable web client*, set port to 9091 (From edit -> preference -> web ) if necessary

Comment: http://www.omgchrome.com/install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-13-10/
This claims there is a dependency issues.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/108925/how-to-tell-chrome-what-to-do-with-a-magnet-link

Comment: I tried this. It didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

if ur using bittorrent go to preferences-general-click on the tab that says associate with torrents..now it will work when you try magnet link..

Comment: You actually have to add the bittorrent entry to the xdg-open list to make this work with chrome as far as I know. Also bittorrent is a name for the system so almost all bittorrent clients have the word bittorrent in it's name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Open Piratebay magnet link with Transmission Client then on Magnet Link
1 Right Click
2 Copy Link Location
Open Transmission 
File> Open URL

It's Done