# Magnet Links in firefox (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: firefox, qbittorrent

I know this has been asked quite a few times already, however, I still don't have it working.

I'm using Qbittorrent as my torrent program, and I want to be able to open magnet links in Firefox.

I already chose qbittorrent as my magnet application handler (in firefox preferences - applications. I chose qbittorrent, located in `/usr/bin/`).

It's not working. Whenever I click on "download torrent", nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Now that I took another look on my firefox preferences, I see that "magnet" has still "always ask" as its value. I tried to change it, but I can't. It always goes back to "Always ask".

Comment: Just tried the most upvoted answer in the link you gave me, Braim (http://askubuntu.com/questions/311537/torrent-magnet-links-open-new-window-but-not-transmission) and still, nothing changed.

Comment: I tried the first part of your solution and still, no changes. this is getting frustrating.

Comment: I'd like to add that it works flawlessly with Chromium. Oh, and when i go to "applications", in firefox, it still has "always ask" has the magnet value.

Comment: Not a dupe, the problem was in Firefox, not xdg as the duplicated suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already exhausted all solutions, you may want to take a look to your `about:config` page, in Firefox. It should have a boolean called `network.protocol-handler.expose.magnet` and it's value should be `false`.

If you don't have it:

- Right click on an empty area of the `about:config` page
- Select **New** > **Boolean**.
- Name should be `network.protocol-handler.expose.magnet` and the value `false`.
- Restart firefox and try again.

Comment: I didn't have that parameter, and so I added, as you told me to. Still, nothing changed. Wth is wrong with my *"#(/ configuration?

Comment: Alright Braiam. I have it solved. What did I do? Well, what fixed it was a firefox re-install (removed firefox and installed firefox). However, I'll accept your answer. Thank you

Comment: Oh, actually. After re-installation, I went to applications (in Firefox preferences) and added qbittorrent has the magnet value. Whenever I did that pre-reinstalletion, it would always change back to "Always ask". Not this time. And it worked.

Comment: For those of you still struggling, you may also need to temporarily change `network.protocol-handler.expose-all` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem following the comment of @GyörgyAndrasek:

"**For those of you still struggling, you may also need to temporarily change `network.protocol-handler.expose-all` to false**"

The keyword here (not said before) is "temporarily"

Once you are at one click of the magnet link you want to associate with your bit-torrent program, then you change the `network.protocol-handler.expose-all` to false. Then click the magnet link. You get a window like this (sorry, this is in spanish):

[image]

There you can choose the program to open this link and you can make it permanent by ticking the lower check-box.

Then **you must** change the `network.protocol-handler.expose-all` back to true.

---o---

My ubuntu: 16.04 LTS

My Firefox: 56.0 (64-bit)