# Open magnet links from Chrome into KTorrent

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, kde, xdg-open, ktorrent

I'm trying to open magnet links from Chrome into KTorrent 4.3.1 on Kubuntu 13.10.

The problem is that after i click the link, a new notification appears. It says "Examining magnet://..." and will run forever without any result. I can stop the examination manually but it doesn't change anything.

The link won't get into KTorrent.

I followed this guide: https://askubuntu.com/a/133693/128252 , but it didn't change anything.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/133693/242703
I was having the same problem; see if this helps.

Comment: Hey @user242703, this link is in my question: i said that i followed the guide and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add x-scheme-handler/magnet=kde4-ktorrent.desktop to the bottom of /usr/share/applications/defaults.list.

I didn't have to restart anything for it to work.

Comment: I've switched from KTorrent to Deluge, so i can't test the solution. Marking it as accepted so that the question won't be abandoned.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed that this works on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS; exact steps:

1. Open terminal
2. Navigate to /usr/share/applications
3. Execute `sudo gedit defaults.list`
4. Enter your `password`
5. Add `x-scheme-handler/magnet=kde4-ktorrent.desktop` to the bottom
6. Save
7. Close
8. DONE!

Comment: prefer `sudoedit` to `sudo my_favourite_editor` and use `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` to pick your favourite editor once for all.

Comment: I was in a hurry and it worked for me on fedora, thanks

Answer (score 2):

system setting
- file association
   in "known types" find "application" - "x-bittorent"
     in right column "application preference order" up ktorrent

Comment: You can also add x-scheme-handler/magnet to the list instead of editing /usr/share/applications/defaults.list