# Can't open magnet links or APT links with Chromium

Tags: apt, chromium, xdg-open

Chromium browser opens a new window instead of handling magnet links or APT links. I tried to look around and found [How to tell Chrome what to do with a magnet link?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108925/how-to-tell-chrome-what-to-do-with-a-magnet-link) but it doesn’t work for me. I ran : `xdg-mime default deluge.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet` but nothing changed.

`xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet` returns `deluge.desktop`.

And I made sure the name is right.

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 [lxde]

Comment: Problem solved for both APT and Magnets, look below. I answered my own question >.>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Make Chromium or Chrome to open magnet links in LXDE](https://web.archive.org/web/20150731020114/http://www.foresightlinux.se:80/make-chromium-to-open-magnet-links/)

> To make chromium to open magnet links, that most of the torrent sites uses. You need to open terminal and write:
>
> ```sh
> gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/command "transmission %s"
> gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/needs_terminal false -t bool
> gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/magnet/enabled true
> ```
>
> Open `xdg-open` in desired text-editor
>
> ```sh
> sudo medit /usr/bin/xdg-open
> ```
>
> find the lines:
>
> ```sh
> #--------------------------------------
> # Checks for known desktop environments
> # set variable DE to the desktop environments name, lowercase
> detectDE()
> {
>  if [ x"$KDE_FULL_SESSION" = x"true" ]; then DE=kde;
>  elif [ x"$GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID" != x"" ]; then DE=gnome;
>  elif `dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.GetNameOwner string:org.gnome.SessionManager > /dev/null 2>&1` ; then DE=gnome;
>  elif xprop -root _DT_SAVE_MODE 2> /dev/null | grep ' = \"xfce4\"$' >/dev/null 2>&1; then DE=xfce;
>  elif [ x"$DESKTOP_SESSION" == x"LXDE" ]; then DE=lxde;
>  else DE=""
>  fi
> }
> ```
>
> make it to look like this instead:
>
> ```sh
> #--------------------------------------
> # Checks for known desktop environments
> # set variable DE to the desktop environments name, lowercase
> detectDE()
> {
> # if [ x"$KDE_FULL_SESSION" = x"true" ]; then DE=kde;
> # elif [ x"$GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID" != x"" ]; then DE=gnome;
> # elif `dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.GetNameOwner string:org.gnome.SessionManager > /dev/null 2>&1` ; then DE=gnome;
> # elif xprop -root _DT_SAVE_MODE 2> /dev/null | grep ' = \"xfce4\"$' >/dev/null 2>&1; then DE=xfce;
> # elif [ x"$DESKTOP_SESSION" == x"LXDE" ]; then DE=lxde;
> # else DE=""
> # fi
> DE=gnome;
> }
> ```
>
> This will probably work in Arch, Lubuntu, Mint and Fedora. Will work in other Linux OS that uses lxde as desktop environment. This isn’t a optimized hack, if you know another way that works as good as this, let me know.