# Open Torrent URL magnet link in transmission by default in Chrome

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, transmission, utorrent, torrent-client

I tried by searching answer in google and StackOverflow, but none of the solutions worked.

First I run this in terminal: `sudo  grep 'MimeType' /usr/share/applications/transmission-gtk.desktop`

And then this command: `xdg-mime default transmission.desktop mymimetype`

But still, it doesn't set transmission by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell Chrome what to do with a magnet link?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108925/how-to-tell-chrome-what-to-do-with-a-magnet-link)